Did the characters in *Penguin Lost* actually routinely use dollars?
Penguin Lost by Andrey Kurkov is set primarily in post-Soviet Ukraine but periodically refers to characters (such as Andrey Pavlovich) using dollars. For example, on chapter 21:

"Remembered her who you were talking to in the sauna? Time - like money for your board, my money, $50 per diem - is short. No sense in wasting it. Infringing Snail's Law is bad enough. Refusing to talk's even worse."

Does the original also refer to dollars here? Did Andrey Pavlovich really routinely use dollars, or did the translator change the currency? How common would it have been for people to use dollars?

If it was in the 1990s — yeah, they could use US dollars, or just estimate prices in USD. Because in post-USSR countries currency was highly violatile and hyper-inflated. Like, it was just easier to operate in tens of dollars than in millions of ukrainian currency of that time.

The original Russian text for this passage reads:

Я за каждые сутки пятьдесят баксов плачу… И, честно говоря, не вижу
смысла больше тратиться

(I pay fifty bucks every day... And, to be honest, I don't see the point in spending more)
The important phrase is пятьдесят баксов, meaning "fifty bucks" - баксов is pronounced as "baks", and so is a phonetic representation of the slang term "bucks" meaning dollars. By referring to the sum of money as "fifty bucks" Andrey is clearly referring to American dollars, and this is made even clearer in other references in the book. For example, in chapter 18 when Andrey is encouraging the "image consultants" to work more quickly, he places "a $100 bill on the keyboard". In the original text this banknote is referred to as a "стодолларовую" (stodollarovuyu), which is indeed a hundred dollar bill.
Since Ukranianian independence, it has been well-known that the Ukranian economy has been highly dollarized, an economic term for when a foreign currency  performs the major functions of money alongside the domestic currency. There are several reasons for this, and a nice summary can be read in a conference paper by Elisabeth S. Curtis, Roy Gardner and Christopher J. Waller, "Dollarization in Ukraine: 1991 to the Present".
The major factor is the perceived or actual weakness of the domestic currency, first the rouble and later the hryvnia. These currencies experienced periods of sustained loss of value, leading to the use of the dollar as "a store of value". This was particularly important when the economy hit phases of hyperinflation - money issued by the government rapidly lost value, but dollars would remain stable.
The dollar also became the preferred form of exchange for what is called the "shadow economy". Most of the people Victor encounters in Penguin Lost are engaged in some form of criminal activity, and so dollars, being untraceable and not taxed, are the natural medium of exchange. Gardner et al. note:

Just prior to independence, the ratio of shadow economy to official
GDP in Ukraine was 16%. During the period 1990-93, that ratio rose to
33%. In the  period 1994-95, it rose still further to 50%. At that
level, one-third of all economic  activity  in  Ukraine  takes  place
in  the  unreported  sector  of  the  economy

[emphasis mine]
